# What is the Success Rate of Global Postural Reeducaton for Treatment for Myelopathy

Tags: spine, neck, myelopathy

How successful is Global Postural Reeducation (RGP) as a non-invasive treatment for cervical myelopathy?

How well does it work?

Comment: Hey there Arturino, welcome to Health SE! I noticed your question and wanted to offer you a suggestion, if I may. You reference RGP as a possible treatment for cervical myelopathy. After a quick search I can tell you that I can't seem to find any references to a treatment called RGP in the scientific literature, beyond the rgp series of viral env proteins which have fairly little to do with myelopathy. If you could provide a bit more context, you'd be far more likely to receive a helpful answer. You would also be asking a question much more likely to help future generations of Health SE users.

Comment: http://www.fisioclinic.com/public/sito/documenti/ext/Global_Postural_Reeducation%20-%20Emiliano%20Grossi.pdf @TheEnvironmentalist

Comment: I edited your question to reflect this, and make it more useful to other Health SE users